# JIRA IssueInputParameters - a builder that specifies issue values

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to follow up this [guide](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/issues/guide-performing-issue-operations), but I have an error on issueInputParameters (Package issueInputParameters does not exist). My code is

```
 IssueService issueService = ComponentAccessor.getIssueService();
final IssueService.IssueResult issueResult = issueService.getIssue(null, "JRA-1234");
final MutableIssue mutableIssue = issueResult.getIssue();

IssueInputParameters issueInputParameters = issueService.newIssueInputParameters();
issueInputParameters.setProjectId(12345L).setIssueTypeId("2");
```

I can't figure out what is the problem. I have added the com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParameters too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. I have added an extra .jar file which was related for the java client and probably there was a conflict between the java .jar and the api .jar.